# Linux SPI driver crasj

Tags: linux-device-driver, interrupt, spi

I am trying to write a SPI driver for Angstrom Linux 2.6.36 for Gumstix Overo Fire. My driver keeps on crashing in the interrupt handler. Here is the full code

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/err.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/smp_lock.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/spi/spi.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <mach/gpio.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/hrtimer.h>

#define IRQ_PIN 10

#define SPI_BUFF_SIZE   4
#define USER_BUFF_SIZE  128

#define SPI_BUS 1
#define SPI_BUS_CS1 1
#define SPI_BUS_SPEED 1500000

unsigned char *buff_even = 0;
unsigned char *buff_odd = 0;
unsigned char *temp_buff = 0;
unsigned int sample_counter = 0;  
unsigned int buff_counter = 0;  
unsigned int current_buffer = 0;  
unsigned int local_current_buffer = 0;  
unsigned int local_sample_counter = 0;
unsigned int num_reads = 0;
unsigned int num_miss_samples = 0;
unsigned int regval = 0;

#define LIMIT (4000)
#define BUFF_SIZE (4*LIMIT)

#define MAJOR_NUM 100
#define READ_CURR_COUNTER _IOWR(MAJOR_NUM, 1, int)
#define READ_BUFF     _IOWR(MAJOR_NUM, 2, int)
#define READ_CURR_BUFF_NO _IOWR(MAJOR_NUM, 3, int)
#define READ_REGISTER _IOWR(MAJOR_NUM, 4, unsigned char)
#define WRITE_REGISTER _IOWR(MAJOR_NUM, 5, int)
#define START_READ _IOWR(MAJOR_NUM, 6, int)
#define STOP_READ _IOWR(MAJOR_NUM, 7, int)

const char this_driver_name[] = "adc";

static int running = 0;
static int resetting = 0;
static int reading = 0;

struct spike_control
{
    struct spi_message msg;
    struct spi_transfer transfer;
    u8 *tx_buff; 
    u8 *rx_buff;
};

static struct spike_control spike_ctl;

struct spike_dev
{
    struct semaphore spi_sem;
    struct semaphore fop_sem;
    dev_t devt;
    struct cdev cdev;
    struct class *class;
    struct spi_device *spi_device;
    char *user_buff;
    u8 test_data;   
    int irq;    
};

static struct spike_dev spike_dev;

static DEFINE_MUTEX(list_lock);
static DEFINE_MUTEX(count_lock);

static int status;

static void spike_completion_handler(void *arg)
{
    local_sample_counter++;

    if (sample_counter >= local_sample_counter + 1)
        num_miss_samples++;

    if (current_buffer == 0)
    {
        buff_even[buff_counter++] = spike_ctl.rx_buff[0];
        buff_even[buff_counter++] = spike_ctl.rx_buff[1];
        buff_even[buff_counter++] = spike_ctl.rx_buff[2];
        buff_even[buff_counter++] = spike_ctl.rx_buff[3];
    }
    else if (current_buffer == 1)
    {
        buff_odd[buff_counter++] = spike_ctl.rx_buff[0];
        buff_odd[buff_counter++] = spike_ctl.rx_buff[1];
        buff_odd[buff_counter++] = spike_ctl.rx_buff[2];
        buff_odd[buff_counter++] = spike_ctl.rx_buff[3];
    }

    memset(spike_ctl.rx_buff, 0, SPI_BUFF_SIZE);

    if (sample_counter == LIMIT)
    {
        buff_counter = 0;
        mutex_lock(&count_lock);
        if (current_buffer == 0)
            current_buffer = 1;
        else
            current_buffer = 0;
        sample_counter = 0; 
        mutex_unlock(&count_lock);
        local_sample_counter = 0;
    }

}

static irqreturn_t adc_handler(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    sample_counter++;   

    spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);   

    spike_ctl.msg.complete = spike_completion_handler;
    spike_ctl.msg.context = NULL;

    spike_ctl.transfer.tx_buf = NULL;
    spike_ctl.transfer.rx_buf = spike_ctl.rx_buff;
    spike_ctl.transfer.len = 4;

    spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
    status = spi_async(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static void resetbuffers(void)
{
    local_sample_counter = 0;
    sample_counter = 0;
    num_miss_samples = 0;
    current_buffer = 0;
    buff_counter = 0;   
    memset(spike_ctl.rx_buff, 0, SPI_BUFF_SIZE);
    memset(spike_ctl.tx_buff, 0, SPI_BUFF_SIZE);
    memset(buff_even, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
    memset(buff_odd, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
    memset(temp_buff, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
}

static int read_register(unsigned char addr)
{
    if (down_interruptible(&spike_dev.spi_sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;

    if (!spike_dev.spi_device)
    {
        up(&spike_dev.spi_sem);
        return -ENODEV;
    }

    memset(spike_ctl.rx_buff, 0, SPI_BUFF_SIZE);
    memset(spike_ctl.tx_buff, 0, SPI_BUFF_SIZE);

    spike_ctl.transfer.tx_buf = spike_ctl.tx_buff;
    spike_ctl.transfer.rx_buf = spike_ctl.rx_buff;
    spike_ctl.transfer.len = 1;

    spike_ctl.tx_buff[0] = 0x11;//Stop read data continuous
    spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);   
    spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
    status = spi_sync(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);
    __asm__ __volatile__("ldr r0,=0x2710\n\t"
                         ".LOOP1:\n\t"
                         "subs r0,r0,#1\n\t"
                         "bne .LOOP1\n\t");

    spike_ctl.tx_buff[0] = 0x20 + addr;//Address of register
    spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);
    spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
    status = spi_sync(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);
    __asm__ __volatile__("ldr r0,=0x2710\n\t"
                         ".LOOP2:\n\t"
                         "subs r0,r0,#1\n\t"
                         "bne .LOOP2\n\t");

    spike_ctl.tx_buff[0] = 0;//Number of registers to read minus 1
    spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);
    spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
    status = spi_sync(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);
    __asm__ __volatile__("ldr r0,=0x2710\n\t"
                         ".LOOP3:\n\t"
                         "subs r0,r0,#1\n\t"
                         "bne .LOOP3\n\t");

    spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);
    spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
    status = spi_sync(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);
    __asm__ __volatile__("ldr r0,=0x2710\n\t"
                         ".LOOP4:\n\t"
                         "subs r0,r0,#1\n\t"
                         "bne .LOOP4\n\t");

    printk(KERN_ALERT "%x\n",spike_ctl.rx_buff[0]);
    regval = spike_ctl.rx_buff[0];

//  spike_ctl.tx_buff[0] = 0x10;//Start read data continuous
//  spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);   
//  spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
//  status = spi_sync(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);

    up(&spike_dev.spi_sem);

    return status;
}

static int write_register(unsigned char addr, unsigned char val)
{
    if (down_interruptible(&spike_dev.spi_sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;

    if (!spike_dev.spi_device)
    {
        up(&spike_dev.spi_sem);
        return -ENODEV;
    }

    memset(spike_ctl.rx_buff, 0, SPI_BUFF_SIZE);
    memset(spike_ctl.tx_buff, 0, SPI_BUFF_SIZE);

    spike_ctl.transfer.tx_buf = spike_ctl.tx_buff;
    spike_ctl.transfer.rx_buf = spike_ctl.rx_buff;
    spike_ctl.transfer.len = 1;

    spike_ctl.tx_buff[0] = 0x11;//Stop read data continuous
    spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);   
    spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
    status = spi_sync(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);
    __asm__ __volatile__("ldr r0,=0x2710\n\t"
                         ".LOOP5:\n\t"
                         "subs r0,r0,#1\n\t"
                         "bne .LOOP5\n\t");

    spike_ctl.tx_buff[0] = 0x40 + addr;//Address of register
    spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);
    spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
    status = spi_sync(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);
    __asm__ __volatile__("ldr r0,=0x2710\n\t"
                         ".LOOP6:\n\t"
                         "subs r0,r0,#1\n\t"
                         "bne .LOOP6\n\t");

    spike_ctl.tx_buff[0] = 0;//Number of registers to read minus 1
    spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);
    spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
    status = spi_sync(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);
    __asm__ __volatile__("ldr r0,=0x2710\n\t"
                         ".LOOP7:\n\t"
                         "subs r0,r0,#1\n\t"
                         "bne .LOOP7\n\t");

    spike_ctl.tx_buff[0] = val;//Value to write
    spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);
    spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
    status = spi_sync(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);
    __asm__ __volatile__("ldr r0,=0x2710\n\t"
                         ".LOOP8:\n\t"
                         "subs r0,r0,#1\n\t"
                         "bne .LOOP8\n\t");

    spike_ctl.tx_buff[0] = 0x10;//Start read data continuous
    spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);   
    spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
    status = spi_sync(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);

//  spike_ctl.tx_buff[0] = 0x10;//Start read data continuous
//  spi_message_init(&spike_ctl.msg);   
//  spi_message_add_tail(&spike_ctl.transfer, &spike_ctl.msg);
//  status = spi_sync(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);

    up(&spike_dev.spi_sem);

    return status;
}

static long adc_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    unsigned char addr;
    switch(cmd) 
    {
    case READ_CURR_COUNTER: 
        mutex_lock(&count_lock);
        local_current_buffer = current_buffer;  
        local_sample_counter = sample_counter;
        mutex_unlock(&count_lock);
        copy_to_user((void *)arg, &local_sample_counter, sizeof(unsigned int));
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Read current counter %d\n",local_sample_counter);
        break;
    case READ_BUFF: 
        mutex_lock(&count_lock);
        local_current_buffer = current_buffer;  
        local_sample_counter = sample_counter;
        mutex_unlock(&count_lock);
        if (local_current_buffer == 0)
        {
            memcpy(temp_buff,buff_odd, BUFF_SIZE);
//          memset(temp_buff, 'Q', BUFF_SIZE);          
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(temp_buff,buff_even, BUFF_SIZE);
//          memset(temp_buff, 'T', BUFF_SIZE);          
        }
        copy_to_user((void *)arg, temp_buff, BUFF_SIZE);
        num_reads++;
        break;
    case READ_CURR_BUFF_NO: 
        mutex_lock(&count_lock);
        local_current_buffer = current_buffer;  
        local_sample_counter = sample_counter;
        mutex_unlock(&count_lock);
        copy_to_user((void *)arg, &local_current_buffer, sizeof(int));
        break;
    case READ_REGISTER: 
        get_user(addr, (unsigned char *)arg);
        disable_irq(spike_dev.irq);
        read_register(addr);
        enable_irq(spike_dev.irq);
        copy_to_user((void *)arg, &regval, sizeof(int));
        break;
    case WRITE_REGISTER:    
        disable_irq(spike_dev.irq);

        enable_irq(spike_dev.irq);
        //copy_to_user((void *)arg, &local_current_buffer, sizeof(int));
        break;

    default:
        return -ENOTTY;
    }
    return 1;

}

static int spike_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{   
    int status = 0;

    if (down_interruptible(&spike_dev.fop_sem)) 
        return -ERESTARTSYS;

    if (!spike_dev.user_buff) {
        spike_dev.user_buff = kmalloc(USER_BUFF_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!spike_dev.user_buff) 
            status = -ENOMEM;
    }   

    up(&spike_dev.fop_sem);

    return status;
}

static int spike_probe(struct spi_device *spi_device)
{
    if (down_interruptible(&spike_dev.spi_sem))
        return -EBUSY;

    spike_dev.spi_device = spi_device;

    printk(KERN_ALERT "SPI[%d] max_speed_hz %d Hz\n", spi_device->chip_select, spi_device->max_speed_hz);

    up(&spike_dev.spi_sem);

    return 0;
}

static int spike_remove(struct spi_device *spi_device)
{
    if (down_interruptible(&spike_dev.spi_sem))
        return -EBUSY;

    spike_dev.spi_device = NULL;

    up(&spike_dev.spi_sem);

    return 0;
}

static int __init add_spike_device_to_bus(void)
{
    struct spi_master *spi_master;
    struct spi_device *spi_device;
    struct device *pdev;
    char buff[64];
    int status = 0;

    spi_master = spi_busnum_to_master(SPI_BUS);
    if (!spi_master)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "spi_busnum_to_master(%d) returned NULL\n",
            SPI_BUS);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Missing modprobe omap2_mcspi?\n");
        return -1;
    }

    spi_device = spi_alloc_device(spi_master);
    if (!spi_device)
    {
        put_device(&spi_master->dev);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "spi_alloc_device() failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    spi_device->chip_select = SPI_BUS_CS1;

    /* Check whether this SPI bus.cs is already claimed */
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%s.%u", 
            dev_name(&spi_device->master->dev),
            spi_device->chip_select);

    pdev = bus_find_device_by_name(spi_device->dev.bus, NULL, buff);
    if (pdev)
    {
        /* We are not going to use this spi_device, so free it */ 
        spi_dev_put(spi_device);

        /* 
         * There is already a device configured for this bus.cs  
         * It is okay if it us, otherwise complain and fail.
         */
        if (pdev->driver && pdev->driver->name && strcmp(this_driver_name, pdev->driver->name))
        {
            printk(KERN_ALERT 
                "Driver [%s] already registered for %s\n",
                pdev->driver->name, buff);
            status = -1;
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        spi_device->max_speed_hz = SPI_BUS_SPEED;
        spi_device->mode = SPI_MODE_0;
        spi_device->bits_per_word = 8;
        spi_device->irq = -1;
        spi_device->controller_state = NULL;
        spi_device->controller_data = NULL;
        strlcpy(spi_device->modalias, this_driver_name, SPI_NAME_SIZE);

        status = spi_add_device(spi_device);        
        if (status < 0)
        {   
            spi_dev_put(spi_device);
            printk(KERN_ALERT "spi_add_device() failed: %d\n", 
                status);        
        }               
    }

    put_device(&spi_master->dev);

    return status;
}

static struct spi_driver spike_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = this_driver_name,
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    },
    .probe = spike_probe,
    .remove = __devexit_p(spike_remove),    
};

static int __init spike_init_spi(void)
{
    int error;

    spike_ctl.tx_buff = kmalloc(SPI_BUFF_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL | GFP_DMA);
    if (!spike_ctl.tx_buff)
    {
        error = -ENOMEM;
        goto spike_init_error;
    }

    spike_ctl.rx_buff = kmalloc(SPI_BUFF_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL | GFP_DMA);
    if (!spike_ctl.rx_buff)
    {
        error = -ENOMEM;
        goto spike_init_error;
    }

    error = spi_register_driver(&spike_driver);
    if (error < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "spi_register_driver() failed %d\n", error);
        goto spike_init_error;
    }

    error = add_spike_device_to_bus();
    if (error < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "add_spike_to_bus() failed\n");
        spi_unregister_driver(&spike_driver);
        goto spike_init_error;  
    }

    spike_dev.irq = OMAP_GPIO_IRQ(IRQ_PIN);

    return 0;

spike_init_error:

    if (spike_ctl.tx_buff) {
        kfree(spike_ctl.tx_buff);
        spike_ctl.tx_buff = 0;
    }

    if (spike_ctl.rx_buff) {
        kfree(spike_ctl.rx_buff);
        spike_ctl.rx_buff = 0;
    }

    return error;
}

static ssize_t spike_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *offp)
{
    size_t len;
    ssize_t status = 0;

    if (!buff) 
        return -EFAULT;

    if (*offp > 0) 
        return 0;

    if (down_interruptible(&spike_dev.fop_sem)) 
        return -ERESTARTSYS;

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Interrupt triggered %d Missed packet %d\n", sample_counter, num_miss_samples);

    up(&spike_dev.fop_sem);

    return status;  
}

static ssize_t spike_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    size_t len; 
    ssize_t status = 0;

    if (down_interruptible(&spike_dev.fop_sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;

    memset(spike_dev.user_buff, 0, 16);
    len = count > 8 ? 8 : count;

    if (copy_from_user(spike_dev.user_buff, buff, len))
    {
        status = -EFAULT;
        goto spike_write_done;
    }

    /* we'll act as if we looked at all the data */
    status = count;

    /* but we only care about the first 5 characters */
    if (!strnicmp(spike_dev.user_buff, "inc", 3))
    {
        disable_irq(spike_dev.irq);
        write_register(1,0x62);
        resetbuffers();
        printk(KERN_ALERT "4000 samples per second\n");
        enable_irq(spike_dev.irq);
    } 

    if (!strnicmp(spike_dev.user_buff, "dec", 3))
    {
        disable_irq(spike_dev.irq);
        write_register(1,0x52);
        resetbuffers();
        printk(KERN_ALERT "1000 samples per second\n");
        enable_irq(spike_dev.irq);
    } 

    if (!strnicmp(spike_dev.user_buff, "stop", 4))
    {
        disable_irq(spike_dev.irq);
        resetbuffers();
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Driver stopped\n");
    } 

spike_write_done:

    up(&spike_dev.fop_sem);

    return status;
}

static const struct file_operations spike_fops = {
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .open           = spike_open,
    .read           = spike_read,
    .write          = spike_write,
    .unlocked_ioctl = adc_ioctl,    
};

static int __init spike_init_cdev(void)
{
    int error;

    spike_dev.devt = MKDEV(0, 0);

    error = alloc_chrdev_region(&spike_dev.devt, 0, 1, this_driver_name);
    if (error < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "alloc_chrdev_region() failed: %d \n", 
            error);
        return -1;
    }

    cdev_init(&spike_dev.cdev, &spike_fops);
    spike_dev.cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;

    error = cdev_add(&spike_dev.cdev, spike_dev.devt, 1);
    if (error)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "cdev_add() failed: %d\n", error);
        unregister_chrdev_region(spike_dev.devt, 1);
        return -1;
    }   

    return 0;
}

static int __init spike_init_class(void)
{
    spike_dev.class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, this_driver_name);

    if (!spike_dev.class)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "class_create() failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (!device_create(spike_dev.class, NULL, spike_dev.devt, NULL, this_driver_name))
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "device_create(..., %s) failed\n",
            this_driver_name);
        class_destroy(spike_dev.class);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int __init spike_init(void)
{

    int result;
    memset(&spike_dev, 0, sizeof(spike_dev));
    memset(&spike_ctl, 0, sizeof(spike_ctl));

    sema_init(&spike_dev.spi_sem, 1);
    sema_init(&spike_dev.fop_sem, 1);

    buff_even = kmalloc(BUFF_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
    buff_odd  = kmalloc(BUFF_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
    temp_buff = kmalloc(BUFF_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);

    if ( buff_even == 0 )
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to allocate buffer even\n");

    if ( buff_odd == 0 )
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to allocate buffer odd\n");

    if ( temp_buff == 0 )
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to temp buffer\n");

    if (spike_init_cdev() < 0) 
        goto fail_1;

    if (spike_init_class() < 0)  
        goto fail_2;

    if (spike_init_spi() < 0) 
        goto fail_3;

    result = request_irq(spike_dev.irq, adc_handler, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING, "adc", &spike_dev);

    if (result < 0)
    {
                printk(KERN_ALERT "request_irq failed: %d\n", result);
                return -1;
    }

    return 0;

fail_3:
    device_destroy(spike_dev.class, spike_dev.devt);
    class_destroy(spike_dev.class);

fail_2:
    cdev_del(&spike_dev.cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(spike_dev.devt, 1);

fail_1:
    return -1;
}
module_init(spike_init);

static void __exit spike_exit(void)
{

    disable_irq(spike_dev.irq);
    free_irq(spike_dev.irq, &spike_dev);
    gpio_free(IRQ_PIN);

    spi_unregister_device(spike_dev.spi_device);
    spi_unregister_driver(&spike_driver);

    device_destroy(spike_dev.class, spike_dev.devt);
    class_destroy(spike_dev.class);

    cdev_del(&spike_dev.cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(spike_dev.devt, 1);

    if (spike_ctl.tx_buff)
        kfree(spike_ctl.tx_buff);

    if (spike_ctl.rx_buff)
        kfree(spike_ctl.rx_buff);

    if (spike_dev.user_buff)
        kfree(spike_dev.user_buff);

    if ( buff_even != 0 )
        kfree(buff_even);

    if ( buff_odd != 0 )
        kfree(buff_odd);

    if ( temp_buff != 0 )
        kfree(temp_buff);

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Interrupt triggered %d Missed packet %d\n", sample_counter, num_miss_samples);

}
module_exit(spike_exit);
```

The interrupt handler crashes on the line

```
status = spi_async(spike_dev.spi_device, &spike_ctl.msg);
```

If i comment out this line everything runs fine but of course no data is read from SPI.

Answer (score 1):

Muhammad, maybe you solved this issue by the time.

However, what I see is that you're using mutexes in the SPI completion handler (spike_completion_handler), which is executed in a context that cannot sleep.
Therefore, I would advise to use spinlocks instead.
This is safe to do, because count_lock always protects code that does not sleep.

That may not be the cause of your problem (did not read the whole code), but it's still better to do it this way.